# Installing php extensions in openwrt

Tags: php, openwrt, intl

I am using OpenWRT Barrier Breaker on a Microtik rb450g router board. 
To run php on OpenWRT, I installed php5 packages using opkg.
But now i need to install php extension specifically intl extension so far i learnt that it can be configured by pecl repository which is accessible using php-pear package, so i installed php-pear package in openwrt but when i run pecl it shows error command not found

On my debian machine i successfully installed intl extension via pecl but openwrt doesn't seems to work this way

Anyone have any idea how i should be doing this?

Comment: PECL != PEAR, install PECL then the PECL package. https://pecl.php.net/ Also this question is much better placed on superuser.com

Comment: @burzum i don't get the part "install PECL then the PECL package"

Comment: @burzum pecl is available through pear package isn't it?

Comment: intl is a PECL **not** a PEAR package. "pecl is available through pear" No,  please spend just 5 minutes reading the description of *both* projects to understand the difference! Install PECL then the PECL package called intl...